# ros-kinetic-opencv3 and apriltags regression?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello list,

Using apriltags ([link text](https://github.com/YuehChuan)) worked fine until the last update of kinetic (around 12 december).
Now there is a crash in opencv when doing "roslaunch apriltags usb_cam_apriltags.launch" as soon as a tag is being recognized.
It seems that removing the assertion solves the problem.
See the output below.

What can I do?
Is there e.g. an easy way to replace the opencv3 code from ros-kinetic-opencv3 by using a (patched) version in /usr/local/bin so that ROS will use that?

Thanks in advance, Sietse

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (((((mtype) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) == 1 && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2542

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2542: error: (-215) mtype == type0 || (((((mtype) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) == 1 && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function create

[apriltags-1] process has died [pid 11062, exit code -6, cmd /home/p100213/ROS/ws2/devel/lib/apriltags/apriltags ~image:=/usb_cam/image_raw ~camera_info:=/usb_cam/camera_info ~marker_array:=/apriltags/marker_array ~detections:=/apriltags/detections __name:=apriltags __log:=/home/p100213/.ros/log/09d71dee-e56c-11e7-852c-002481150e15/apriltags-1.log].
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277859/ros-kinetic-opencv3-and-apriltags-regression?/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinxian](https://answers.ros.org/users/31206/pinxian/) on 2017-12-25**:
I have the same problem . Any idea?

**Comment by [dpoiesz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33274/dpoiesz/) on 2018-01-16**:
I'm having a similar issue. Has anyone found a solution?

**Comment by [ashwinvk94](https://answers.ros.org/users/32850/ashwinvk94/) on 2018-01-19**:
I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `apriltags_ros/apriltags/src/TagDetection.cc` change line 95, `cv::Matx33f ...` to :

```
cv::Matx33d cameraMatrix( fx, 0, px,
                          0, fy, py,
                          0,  0,  1);
```

#### **(Just `f` to `d`)**

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-01-25**:
First: the version of apriltags_ros I used was a different one. I now switched to the "regular" and patched it as above.

The error does not occur anymore, and tags are detected, with correct id-number.
But position/orientation is not given. Always all zero's apart from w.
Still anything wrong?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2018-01-25**:
I pushed changes from my other private repository, everything works fine there. [github.com/cosmicog/apriltags_ros](https://github.com/cosmicog/apriltags_ros) (branch: kinetic-devel)

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-01-25**:
It works when using this repository!

I tested it on my home machine using Lunar. Will later test some more on kinetic.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-01-25**:
Note that the version mentioned in the ros-wiki still has to be corrected.

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2018-02-05**:
Eureka! Matx33f -> Matx33d just works ^_^

**Comment by [Alex Beh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33685/alex-beh/) on 2018-02-13**:
why I cannot find the Matx33d above?

I download the package from https://github.com/xenobot-dev/apriltags_ros .

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-02-13**:
See my first comment. Use the version from Orhan or patch the version mentioned in the ros-wiki.

**Comment by [Alex Beh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33685/alex-beh/) on 2018-02-13**:
I am really new to ROS. so just git clone it to my /catkin_ws/src and run catkin_make @ /catkin_ws ?

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2018-02-13**:
Basically, yes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
@Alex Beh: please see #q252478.

There is a little more to it.

**Comment by [Alex Beh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33685/alex-beh/) on 2018-02-13**:
I have successfully install the version from Orhan and rosrun it. But why the problem still come out? Is it because I didn't do calibration of my usb_cam?

**Comment by [Alex Beh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33685/alex-beh/) on 2018-02-13**:
I think the code executed for Orhan's package in terminal is different from my previous package.

I only know two commands to be executed in terminal, any other commands needed?
Terminal 1: roscore
Terminal 2: roslaunch apriltagsros example.launch /usbcam_tag.launch
Terminal 3:
Terminal 4:

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively, a newer version of apriltags is available for kinetic (http://wiki.ros.org/apriltags2_ros).

---

Originally posted by [Nick S](https://answers.ros.org/users/27877/nick-s/) with karma: 21 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2